# loading various images for boolean buttons?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I am creating buttons at runtime, I wanted to add an image for each value true and false, 
so if I have onOff button, true would be green pic, false red. and want this to work for other properties too.

My questions are
1. How to load the pictures to best suit this purpose?
2. How to create the buttons the right way?
3. I was using the same function for Enum buttons,if it looks strange. 
4. I am sure am doing many things wrong, advice please.

```
foreach(p in properties){
if(p is bool){createBoolButton(p);}
//so on

string path;
string path2;
private Control createBoolButton(IProperty p) {
  countControls2 = 1;
  locationY = 10;
  int gbHeight = 2;
  radioButtonY = 10;
  IType pType = p.Type;
  var myP = new MyProperty(p, this);
  if (myP.Value != null) {
  }
  Panel gb = new Panel();
  gb.Location = new Point(locationY, nextLocationX);
  nextLocationX += rbWidth + 10;
  gb.Name = "groupBox" + p.Id;
  gb.Text = p.Id;
  gb.Tag = p;
  bool[] x = { true, false };
  foreach (var t in x) {
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
    rb.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    rb.Width = rbWidth;
    rb.Height = rbHeight;
    rb.Name = t.ToString();
    rb.Text = t.ToString();
    rb.Tag = t;
    countControls++;
    rb.Location = new Point(radioButtonY, radioButtonX);
    if (myP.Value != null && myP.Value.ToString().SafeEquals(rb.Text)) {
      rb.Checked = true;
    }
    radioButtonY += rbHeight;
    gb.Controls.Add(rb);
    rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged;
  }
  gb.Width = rbHeight * gbHeight + 20;
  gb.Height = rbWidth + 10;
  Controls.Add(gb);
  countControls2++;
  return gb;
}
  private void getimagesPath(EnumValue[] TypesArray) {

  foreach (var enumType in TypesArray) {
    string path = @"C:\Folder\" + enumType.Name + ".png";
    string path2 = @"C:\Folder\" + enumType.Name + "_checked.png";
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
    FileInfo fi2 = new FileInfo(path2);
    if (!imagePaths.ContainsKey(enumType.Name) && !imagePaths.ContainsKey(enumType.Name + "_checked")) {
      if (fi.Exists && fi2.Exists) {
        imagePaths.Add(enumType.Name, path);
        imagePaths.Add(enumType.Name + "_checked", path2);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (!imagePaths.ContainsKey(enumType.Name)) {
        imagePaths.Add(enumType.Name, DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) preload them (cache) in sort of resource manager class 2) not sure what problem you have, but if it's radio button, then they have to be in separate containers to work at same time, maybe conside to use `CheckBox`'es instead? 4) depends on problems, idea of generating controls dinamically is not bad, but if you are, to example, working with bit fields, then create designated control what can editing 8-, 16-, 24-, 32- bits values is better idea. To configure sort of settings winforms has `PropertyGrid`, very powerful control.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think In this case you don't need pictures. Just change the backColor of the buttons.
2. Sample code for creating buttons:

   ```
   Dim pnl as new Panel

   Dim btn as new Button
   btn.Name = "btn1"
   btn.Location = new Point(..., ...)

   pnl.Controls.Add(btn)
   ```

Sorry, but I dont know C#.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your `checked image` and `unchecked image` as `Resources` in your project. Just look in the `Solution Explorer`, you will see there is a `Resources` node under `Properties` node under your project node. Double click on that node and you should know how to add an image to that `Resources`. Once you add images to it, you can access those images easily as I show in the code below. I suppose your checked image is added to `Resources` with name `CheckedImage` and your unchecked image is added to `Resources` with name `UncheckedImage`:

```
//Here is your RadioButton CheckedChanged event handler to change to image accordingly.
private void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;
   button.Image = button.Checked ? Properties.Resources.CheckedImage : Properties.Resources.UncheckedImage;
}
```

Your code is too much redundant and not efficient.

Comment: I know it is, but I am having hard time thinking outside the box, would appreciate any suggestions please

Comment: @justanidiot what do you want more? What is the suggestion about? As I understand, you want to create your own `RadioButton` with your own `Checked and Unchecked images`, by default those images are circles.